In Azure Devops, how can I query all the user stories, and the count of related bugs for each story?
In Azure Devops, how can I query all the user stories and the number of related bugs for each story? Can I create a report/view and schedule sending it to an email address?
Overall, I need a manager's view of all user stories and the number of bugs under each one.
Screenshot for illustration: https://i.sstatic.net/fKiLl6ta.png

You can set up a pipeline with the scheduled triggers. And in the pipeline, you can call the Azure DevOps REST API "Send Mail - Send Mail" to send email for the query result to the specified users.
Below is the sample with the detailed steps to set up the configurations:

Create a Work Item query like as below image shows. It will returns all the User Stories and the linked Bugs of them within a project. From the URL of this query, you can see its ID.


In the project where the Work Item query is in, have a repository that contains a pipeline YAML file and a PowerShell script file.


The content of PowerShell script (wiql-result-send-email.ps1).


param (
    [Alias("org", "o")]
    [string] $organization,

    [Alias("proj", "p")]
    [string] $project,

    [Alias("qid")]
    [string] $queryId,

    [Alias("mail", "ma")]
    [string[]] $emailAddresses
)

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$uri_query = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/queries/${queryId}?`$expand=wiql&api-version=7.1"
$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri_query -Headers $headers
$queryName = $query.name
$queryWiql = $query.wiql

$uri_query_result = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/wiql/${queryId}?api-version=7.1"
$query_result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri_query_result -Headers $headers

$mailMessage = "[User Story ID], [Linked Bug Count]"
$stories = $query_result.workItemRelations | Where-Object { $null -eq $_.source }
foreach ($story in $stories)
{
    $storyId = $story.target.id
    $bugCount = ($query_result.workItemRelations | Where-Object { $_.source.id -eq $storyId }).count
    $mailMessage += "\n${storyId}, ${bugCount}"
}

$userIds = @()
foreach ($emailAddress in $emailAddresses)
{
    $get_userId = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=${emailAddress}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.1"
    $userId = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $get_userId -Headers $headers).value[0].id
    $userIds += $userId
}

$uri_send_mail = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1"
$body_send_mail = (@{
    fields = @(
        "System.Id"
        "System.WorkItemType"
        "System.State"
        "System.Title"
    )
    message = @{
        subject = "Result of Query: ${queryName}"
        body = $mailMessage
        to = @{
            tfIds = $userIds
        }
        cc = @{
            tfIds = $userIds
        }
        replyTo = @{
            tfIds = $userIds
        }
    }
    wiql = $queryWiql
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10).Replace("\\n", "\n")

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri_send_mail -Headers $headers -Body $body_send_mail


The content of the pipeline YAML (wiql-result-send-email.yml).

trigger: none
schedules:
- cron: '0 0 * * *'
  displayName: 'Daily Send'
  branches:
    include:
    - main

parameters:
- name: organization
  displayName: 'Organization Name:'
  type: string
  default: 'myOrg'
- name: project
  displayName: 'Project Name:'
  type: string
  default: 'myProj'
- name: query
  displayName: 'Query ID:'
  type: string
  default: '88064aa6-63fe-47fa-9486-46bb809c84c4'
- name: emails
  displayName: 'List of email addresses (comma separated):'
  type: string
  default: >
    'userMail01@exmpale.com',
    'userMail02@exmpale.com'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Send Query Result Email'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    filePath: 'scripts/wiql-result-send-email.ps1'
    arguments: >
      -o "${{ parameters.organization }}"
      -p "${{ parameters.project }}"
      -qid ${{ parameters.query }}
      -ma ${{ parameters.emails }}


Use the YAML file wiql-result-send-email.yml to create a YAML pipeline.

Since the pipeline has been configured a scheduled trigger, it will automatically trigger a run of this pipeline everyday. at this time, the run will use the default values of parameters and pass them into the PowerShell script for use.

If you manually trigger this pipeline, you can enter different values to override the default ones.




The content of the email message will look like as below.





There is no built-in feature to send the view/query result to email on schedule. You need to do it with automation tool like Power Automate...etc.
Your query will not list the user story which doesn't have Bugs related, use Return all top level items for Filter option to get all user stories even no bugs related.

The user story could have multiple types links, like Bug, tasks, Feature...etc. In DevOps query,it cannot only count the related bug, but count all related links(add Related Link Count column on query result). If you would like to see the count of related bug, you can check Backlog page, add a rollup column  named Count of Bug as below.

As mentioned before, for schedule sending it to an email, you need to achieve it with automation tool, like Power Automate...etc.
Main steps as below:

on azure portal, create a power automate workflow, start with a Recurrence trigger to set the schedule (e.g., daily, weekly).
Add the Get Query Results action, connect to your Azure DevOps organization and project, choose the query you want to run.
Format the Results:
Use the Create HTML Table action to format the query results into an HTML table.
Send an Email:
Add the Send an Email action, specify the recipient's email address, subject, and body. Include the HTML table in the body of the email.
Save and Run.


